# Is there a difference between these two operations?

Tags: c

I would like to ask if there is a difference in the result (s16Result) between

```
int16_t s16X, s16Y, s16Result;

s16Result = (int16_t) (s16X - s16Y);
```

and

```
int16_t s16X, s16Y, s16Result;

s16Result = (int16_t) ((uint16_t) s16X - (uint16_t) s16Y)
```

with s16X and s16Y having the datatype signed integer and therefore having the range -32767...32767 . Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to easily make a test program, where you make one of the values negative, and see the result of the two operations and compare them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Testing one sample in one program in one C implementation does not provide a definitive answer about what the C standard requires generally.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, but it should give a few hints.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but just one example showing that they are not equal is enough to learn that it won't be equal. Which is what would happen now

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: A person who knows the expressions are different and why can use that information to find such an example. But a questioner, by definition, does not have that information, and flailing about for an example is not a good procedure. Instead of snarky comments, it is better to provide answers or useful guidance.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It may or may not. An example at most provides one possible result, whereas the C standard may allow multiple possible results or infinitely many results (undefined behavior). Examples are simply incapable of providing this information.

Comment: Without knowing the definitions of `T_U16`, `_S16` and `s16Result`, it's impossible to say very much.  It wouldn't be hard to write a few lines with those definitions (and those for `s16X` and `s16Y` - code is much clearer than words), and the question would be greatly improved.

Comment: [Related](/q/18195715)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: By the way, when you said it was easy to make a test program, and since we know the two statements have different behaviors as defined by the C standard, what test program were you thinking of? Let’s assume `T_S16` is `int16_t`, `T_U16` is `uint16_t`, and `s16X` and `s16Y` are of type `T_S16`. What test program is easy to construct that shows the statements are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These statements do not generally have the same behavior as defined by the C standard. Consider when `s16X` has the least value of its type (e.g., perhaps `INT_MIN` in an implementation where the `int` type is 16 bits, so it could be −32767) and `s16Y` is 2. Then, in:

```
s16Result = (T_S16) (s16X - s16Y)
```

the expression `s16X - s16Y` overflows—the mathematical result of −32769 is not representable in the `int` type, and the C standard does not define the result.

However, in:

```
s16Result = (T_S16) ((T_U16) s16X - (T_U16) s16Y)
```

the `T_U16` type is presumably an unsigned 16-bit type. In this case, `s16X` is converted to the 16-bit type by adding or subtracting 65536, yielding 32769. `s16Y` retains its value of 2. Then the subtraction yields 32767. finally, this result is converted to the `T_S16` type, which keeps the value 32767.

Thus, the statement with unsigned arithmetic may have a defined value in some situations where the statement with signed arithmetic does not have a value defined by the C standard.

(The statement with unsigned arithmetic still has undefined behavior if the final result is not representable in the `T_S16` type, as when the final result is a number from 32768 to 65535 rather than from 0 to 32767.)